# Do I have to do the "accommodation registration at local police station" within 24 hours of entry when using Airbnb in China?

Tags: china, accommodation, regulations, airbnb

Do I have to do the "accommodation registration at local police station" within 24 hours of entry if I'm a non-Chinese resident/citizen visiting in China and hosted by some Airbnb host?

---

From the back of the departure card given by the Chinese immigration while entering China:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **somebody has to do it**, so check with your host: if they don't, it's your responsibility.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Airbnb can't do it, it has to be done physically at the police station.  As said, either you or your host has to do it.

Comment: That's good to know. How do hotels take care of it if it has to be done physically at the police station? do they have employees going to the police station every day?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Dunno about China, but in Bosnia, Serbia and Macedonia, hotel staff either store the registration forms for themselves, or give part of the form to the police in person. Or they may send the data electronically to the police and hand the guest the confirmation receipt

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt They fill out a form which presumably gets turned into the police.  It's simpler than what you get when you register on your own.

Comment: In China hotels normally take a copy of your passport or identity card as part of the guest registration process. I've seen this done with hotels that really just one-night apartment rentals. I imagine this is given to the local police.

Comment: I should add that this policy is often unenforced, but I advise erring on the side of caution; if you do __get__ caught, you'll be in trouble. See [this Engrish poster](https://www.whatsonweibo.com/china-now-police-notice-foreigners/) which created quite a bit of laughter on the Chinese internet for some possible consequences :-)